# SQL Server: Help in table design

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have an application that displays posts, and for each post the users can say if they like the post or not.
For each post I should display how many users likes it and how many dont like it.
Suppose I have these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Post](
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Quotation] [text] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Post] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserPostAction]( --Every action of the user (like or dislike) is     recorded to this table
[PostId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[ActionValue] [int] NOT NULL, --Like / Dislike
CONSTRAINT [PK_UserPostAction] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[PostId] ASC,
[UserId] ASC,    
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What is the best way, performance wise,  to have a select statement that returns a list of posts which contains the like/dislike statistics already in:

A)  Add 2 more columns to Post table: TotalLike and TotalDislike, and when inserting a new record to UserPostAction I will update these columns? This way, when selecting posts from Post table I will have the statistics already calculated.

B)  Add a third table: PostStat ([PostId], [TotalLike], [TotalDislike]) and update the table in a batch process. The select statement will use Inner Join on Post.Id = PostStat.PostId to retrieve the statistics.

C)  Any other way you can think of.

Hopefully, I will have a DB with millions of posts, and the Post table will be queried very often by a lot of users.
Keep in mind that the statistics is updated very frequently, because a lot of users will like or dislike a lot of posts. It means (maybe) performing a lot of updates and table locking, which will interfere with the select statement that returns posts to be displayed.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Shouldn't be any risk of table locking if you're updating single posts at a time. Also any reason you're using text vs (n)varchar(max) data type?

Answer (score 1):

```
I will have a DB with millions of posts
```

don't think this is enough reason to maintain duplicate data on your DB.

You already have all the info you need on your current tables. Its a matter of building the right indexes and you can easily count how many users liked\unliked the post.

If you are really unconformable with this approach, I suggest implementing option A with triggers on the UserPostAction table to maintain your 2 new columns.

Comment: Counting like/dislike from the UserPostAction table on every "Get" will not scale well.

Comment: that is a very vague statement. I can or cannot be true based on several factors and we really cant conclude based on the amount of info he gave us (which was only one, really). That's why I gave 2 options

Comment: Diego - What indexes do you suggest? this approach seems expensive to me no matter the indexes.

Comment: you would have to analyse that. It would be different if you are planning on grouping your results by post ID and getting both results (like\dislike) in the same query or if your are grouping by postId and actionValue and running two queries. You'll have to check the exec plans. But my point is that "millions of rows" are not that much data to start thinking on data duplication on your DB (it may be the case, but I think you should explore other options before going that way)

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation and I choose the strategy A:

- Putting that information on the main table is the "normal" choice given that you'll have a one-to-one relationship between Post and PostStat.
- you won't have to do a join between the Post and PostStats tables every time you query Posts, that I assume is more expensive than accessing a single table containing the same columns scattered in the two.
- if you'll update the like/dislike counters with a trigger (that's what I did), having the column on the parent table will make life so much easier... In fact you'll just have to write an "update post set likes = likes + 1 where postId = :new.postId" (oracle sql syntax), and the referential integrity on postId will guarantee that you have a row to update there.

Knowing that writes don't block reads (in fact they will just read the previous value until the transaction is completed) I doubt you'll have locking issues putting the columns on the main table.